# Match two datasets on two columns in python (date being one of these values)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a two datasets where I would like to match on the date and a specific column.

**Data**

df1

```
label   date        type1   stat1
111     7/1/2021    y      n
222     8/1/2021    y      n
333     9/1/2021    n      y
```

df2

```
  id   date_1      type   stat
  111  7/1/2021    y      n
  222  7/20/2021   y      n
  333  7/30/2021   n      y
```

**Desired**

```
id   date        type   stat   date_1      label     type1   stat1
111  7/1/2021    y      n      7/1/2021    111       y       n
222  8/1/2021    y      n
333  9/1/2021    n      y
```

**Doing**

I figure I can treat as a string and do a left join. How would I join on
date value as well as the type column?
Any insight is appreciated.

```
df4 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on=["date","type1"], right_on=["date_1", "type"])
```

Although the dates are true dates

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can use whatever you want as the merge keys, so long as the values are hashable,

Comment: the datatype of keys you are joining on doesn't matter as long as they are compatible on both sides/.  so your code should give you what you want

Comment: I think your code should be working as it is.

Comment: ok thank you for input

Comment: @sophocles I updated - I would like to match on two columns: date and type1

Comment: ok @eshirvana I updated, as I would like match on date and type1 column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then it should be like this :

```
df3 = df1.merge(server, left_on=['date','type1'], right_on=['date_1','type'], how='left')
```

output:

```
>>>label      date type1 stat1     id    date_1 type stat
0    111  7/1/2021     y     n  111.0  7/1/2021    y    n
1    222  8/1/2021     y     n    NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN
2    333  9/1/2021     n     y    NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: hmm ok thank you but my table that is joined is 100% blank-  will look at the date - for some reason it is not joining on date I believe

Comment: @Lynn  I double-checked. It works ok for given sample data though

Comment: Ok will troubleshoot my dataset thanks